# How to load images into a listbox asynchronously?

Tags: c#, async-await

With this code, the use has to wait until all the images are loaded. I want to load these images into the listbox asynchronously so the user won't have to wait. How do I do that?

```
    public photos()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        refreshView();
    }

    private void refreshView()
    {
        string[] fileNames = storage.GetFileNames();
        for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.Length; i++)
        {
            image = new Image();
            FileStream jpegStream = storage.OpenFile(fileNames[i], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            image.Source = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(jpegStream, 200, 200);
            jpegStream.Dispose();
            photoList.Items.Add(image);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using BackgroundWorkerThread.

Comment: Also don't refresh the view in the constructor. Use OnLoad or something like this.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. There's no need to include tags in your title. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147072 for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `BackgroundWorker`.

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += (o, args) =>
    {
        //now you have a choice: get all images and add when all are retrieved,
        //or get images asynchronously here too...
        //probably best to do the latter:

        string[] fileNames = storage.GetFileNames();
        Parallell.ForEach(fileNames, file =>
        {
            Image image = new Image();
            using(FileStream jpegStream = storage.OpenFile(fileNames[i], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                image.Source = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(jpegStream, 200, 200);
            }
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => photoList.Items.Add(image));
        }
    };
bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: Better UI ex with read image, add image than with read ALL images and then do add? If lots of large images the read of all images might take time?

Comment: I'm always leary of background interactions with the UI. The form could be closed before the work is complete.  `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => if (!photoList.IsDisposed) photoList.Items.Add(image));`

Comment: Let me try that again, `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => if (photoList.IsDisposed) image.Dispose() else photoList.Items.Add(image)) ;`